# Does the line integral definition of Work involve distance or displacement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, distance, displacement

My textbook reports the following definition of Work:

[image]

where d**s** is the infinitesimal displacement.

I know that an infinitesimal displacement is usually denoted by d**r** and I also know that the magnitude of d**r** is given by ds (infinitesimal distance) Now, if we are talking about displacement (in Work definition), why should we use d**s** instead of d**r**?

I ask this because my textbook always refers to infinitesimal displacement as d**r**. I have always associated 's' to distance, so I see d**s** as an infinitesimal "distance vector", but I am quite sure that distance is only a scalar quantity, not a vector.

Comment: Of course it does...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its just a matter of what you use to call as displacement and as distance .

I have seen the usage of:

- dx
- ds
- dr

as the displacement too.

[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work_and_energy) says :

> The work done by a constant force of magnitude F on a point that moves a displacement (not distance) s in the direction of the force is the product,
>   W = Fs.

Note the usage of s as dispacement .
All in all , its the displacement that is used in calculating work and one may refer to it in many ways.(probably your textbook used different notations in different chapters)

And Distance is a scalar quantity.